# COM: Return copy of string, or actual value?

Tags: c++, windows, com, idl

I have a `[dual]` interface implementing `IDispatch`, something like this:

```
[dual, ...]
interface IMyInterface : IDispatch
{
    [id(1), propget] HRESULT StringValue([out, string, retval] OLECHAR const ** str);
};
```

My backing object for `IMyInterface` has a member variable, `d_str`:

```
class CBackingObject : public IMyInterface
{
    std::basic_string<OLECHAR> d_str;
    ...
};
```

What's the COM convention for returning `StringValue` property? Should I return `d_str.data()`, or a *copy* of it? Do clients automatically take on the responsibility of freeing the string returned by a string-valued property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say, it is not an Automation compatible signature.  An IDispatch interface requires passing strings as a BSTR, a string that's allocated on the COM heap.  The contract for an [out,retval] is that the interface method allocates the string with SysAllocString() and the caller releases it with SysFreeString().

Your code as written is likely to misbehave.  You *must* at least use SysAllocString, a copy in other words.  You might get away with the OLECHAR** declaration in your IDL but it is quite unhealthy, this goes wrong when the call is early-bound and marshaled across an apartment boundary.  You'd better fix it, use BSTR* instead.

Comment: Thanks Hans -- great answer and I will fix accordingly to follow the contract. Three questions: (1) I should return a *copy* that is SysAllocString()'d? (2) If I have a corresponding `propput`, I should copy the incoming BSTR as well? (3) Are you able to link me to a doc that explains the contract?

Comment: SysAllocString already makes the copy.  The setter should copy the string content, not the pointer, whatever format you want to keep it in.  Use google for links, amazon for books.